# How can I save a figure in a .fig file as an image with higher dpi?

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure

I have a figure file (.fig) that I want to save as a 900 dpi TIFF file.

Normally, if I create the plot myself:

```
figure;
plot(x,y);
```

Then the command:

```
print(gcf,'test.tif','-dpng','-r900');
```

Would produce the image I want. However, I only have the .fig file and MATLAB does not recognize that plot window by the keyword `gcf`. Is there any way to save a high resolution image from a .fig file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [`gcf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcf.html) simply returns the current figure handle, so if you've recreated the figure by opening your .fig file with [`openfig`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/openfig.html), it should work. The following example creates two identical TIFF files at a resolution of 900 dpi, one before saving a .fig and one after loading the .fig:

```
surf(peaks);           % Create a surface plot
print(gcf, 'before_save.tif', '-dpng', '-r900');  % Save figure as an image
savefig('peaks.fig');  % Save figure in a .fig file
close(gcf);            % Close figure

openfig('peaks.fig');  % Recreate figure from .fig file
print(gcf, 'after_save.tif', '-dpng', '-r900');  % Save new figure as an image
```